# Can we get the information of the credit cards which are pending for authorization from passbook without generating a payment request to apple?

Tags: ios9, credit-card, passbook, applepay

As part of Mastercard Yellowpath Solution for credit card registration on passbook, we are looking into using mobile app for yellow path  resolution.

We need to  know  some attributes of pending activation credit card from passbook.
We need to validate the credit card info before we can request Mastercard to approve the tokenization of card.

1. Can we get the information of the credit cards which are pending for authorization from passbook without generating a payment request to apple? (Since we are not doing any in app purchases in our app)
2. If so do we still require to get the merchant certificate for our app?
3. Last  4 digits of credit card is what  we are looking to read from pass file. Any suggestions on how we can read the pending activation credit card pass file ?

Comment: Any help is much appreciated